# How do I cut out a shape in a background sprite in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the desired effect: https://gyazo.com/1e98ca2709282d0163702b8ce829480d

The circle has to be able to move across the background and remove the background as it goes.

I found older tutorials but they seemed to used shaders which I couldn't wrap my head around. I also tried stencil shaders but realised they couldn't do what I wanted.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a simple mask shader. There are many solution and examples online. For the effect you want you could use a shader like this:

```
Shader "MaskedTexture"
{
   Properties
   {
      _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Mask ("Culling Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range (0,1)) = 0.1
   }
   SubShader
   {
      Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
      Lighting Off
      ZWrite Off
      Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
      AlphaTest GEqual [_Cutoff]

      Pass
      {
         SetTexture [_Mask] {combine texture}
         SetTexture [_MainTex] {combine texture, previous}
      }
   }
}
```

And to move the mask simply change its offset.